# Web API 2.0 deserealise g-recaptcha-response

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Im stuck with some strange deseralization problem. It must work but it doesnt. So here is model that I expecting in my method:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class RequestACallbackModel
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string reason { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "g-recaptcha-response")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="g-recaptcha-response")]
    public string grecaptcharesponse { get; set; }
}
```

And the method

```
[HttpPost]
public BaseFormResponseModel Submit(RequestACallbackModel model)
{
     . . . 
}
```

Global.asax settings:

```
public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;

    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Default",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new {Id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
}
```

When I send POST on this controller I get everything but captcha response.

As you can see I tried both ways on property name settings and none of them works.

---

Update found that our form is submitted with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so these attributes is not viable, but which are?